# How to deploy de-Lombok-ed sources with maven

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I use Lombok in my library's code and want to use delombok'ed sources when deploying library JAR with sources to maven repository.
How to configure Maven to achieve this?

Update: Most likely, you don't need to deploy delombok'ed sources (check comments below this question for details)

Comment: What is the purpose of deploying delomboked sources that are both looking machine-generated and not matching the original source code?

Comment: This can be useful when during debug I need to jump to an exact line of dependency's code

Comment: But for what reason? Applying Lombok to the code retains the original debug info (source filename, exact line number, etc). Delomboking would cause the lines offset off the original location, wouldn't it?

Comment: It confuses my IDE when "doenloaded from maven repo sources" differ from class bytecode. And with lombok applied, "exact line number" may not exist in the original source file.

Comment: Do you remove debugging info from your deployed artifacts? I mean, it sounds contradicting with the fact that applying Lombok retains the original debugging info.

Comment: Hm.. looks like you're right. I dindnt think from this point of view. Main goal was to stop my IDE being mad because of "sources don't match bytecode" error.

Comment: The question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362413/create-and-install-de-lomboked-source-jar-in-maven

Answer (score 1):

Include following plugins into `pom.xml`'s `build/plugins` section:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>delombok</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
        <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-to-lombok-build</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-delomboked-sources-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <jar
                            destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-sources.jar"
                            basedir="${project.build.directory}/delombok"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-source-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-sources.jar</file>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <classifier>sources</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```